# What is the connection between a derivative and the linear approximation? (First order Taylor)

Tags: complex-analysis

We are talking about Taylor-series in our lecture right now. It generalizes a concept which we should have already understood when we were introducing derivatives.

We have said that:

> *If $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{C},I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $x_0$ then it is equivalent to say that there exists a Linear
>   function $L:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that*
>
> $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)}{h}=0$$

I have understood the proof but not the Statement itself.

Because before the Statement was proved there was a remark which says (translated from German):

*In this formulation the differentiability states that the increase $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ of the function can be approximated so well by the value $L(h)$ of a linear mapping $L$ that the difference $R(h):=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)$ goes with $h\rightarrow 0$ faster to $0$ than $h$ itself*

I don't understand this remark.

Here are my **Questions** what does

- What does *The difference $R(h):=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)$ goes with $h\rightarrow 0$ faster to $0$ than $h$ itself* mean?
- How is this given if above Statement in yellow holds?
- What would it mean if the *increase of the function* could not be approximated *so well* by the value $L(h)$?
- I.e. what would it mean if the difference  *$R(h):=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)$ goes with $h\rightarrow 0$ **slower** to $0$ than $h$ itself* mean?

Comment: It means what is written the limit of the ratio of the error term (the numerator) get  smaller and smaller as compared to $h$.

Comment: I don't understand what it has to do with Velocity , slower , faster?

Comment: It means the ratio goes to $0$.  Both numerator and denominator go to $0$ but the numerator goes to $0$ faster.  If it went to $0$ slower, the ratio would become infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer, addressing your first two questions (since I think you'll be able to figure out the third and fourth once you understand the first two):

---

Let's give an intuitive example first, to motivate our definition.

Consider the functions $x$ versus $x^2$. Both go to zero as $x$ goes to zero - that is, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^2=0.$$ However, although they have the same limit as $x\rightarrow 0$, we can still compare them and say something interesting. Namely, for $x$ very close to zero we have that $x$ is "relatively much bigger than" $x^2$: e.g. taking $x={1\over 1000}$ it should be intuitive that ${1\over 1000}$ is "relatively much bigger than $({1\over 1000})^2={1\over 1000000}$.

- Granted, the absolute difference between the two - namely, ${1\over 1000}-{1\over 1000000}$ - is quite small, but that's pretty big when *compared with* ${1\over 1000}$, and is quite huge when compared with ${1\over 1000000}$.

This can be made precise by looking at the ratios of functions:

> **Definition**: "$f(x)$ goes to zero faster than $g(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$" means "$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{f(x)\over g(x)}=0$."

For example, take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$; then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{f(x)\over g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{x^2\over x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=0,$$ reflecting our previous claim that $x^2$ goes to zero faster than $x$ (as $x\rightarrow 0$).

- It might be more intuitive to think of this in terms of *sequences*: it should be intuitively clear that the sequence $$1,{1\over 2}, {1\over 3},{1\over 4}, ...$$ goes to zero, but the sequence $$1, {1\over 2}, {1\over 4}, {1\over 8}, ...$$ goes to zero much faster. That's essentially what's going on here.

---

To see an example of a function where the desired speed property doesn't hold, look at a specific example - say, $f(x)=\vert x\vert$. Do you see why this *doesn't* have the property in your question?

Comment: I have thought About your answer for a while now and I will Gather my results in this commentsection here:                                                               We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\iff\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}:|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\epsilon\iff |f(x)|<\epsilon |g(x)|< g(x),\text{ if } \epsilon< 1$ That means if we fix a $\epsilon<1$ we will find a respective $\delta$ neighbourhood around Zero ($-\delta<|x|<\delta$) for which we have $f(x)<g(x)$. $g(x)$ can get arbitry smal but in this neighbourhood $f(x)$ is always smaller

Comment: Conveying this result in the situation Right here we can approach $x_0$ get $\epsilon$close to $x_0$. But in a certain $\delta$- neighbourhood the error of the linear Approximation $R(h)$ is always smaller then $\epsilon$. To answer my two remaing Questions. Suppose $R(x)$ does not go to Zero faster than  $h$ then forall linear functions $L:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)}{h}\neq 0$ and suppose $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_(x_0+h)-f(x)}{h}=c$, i.e the Limit exists then we would get a contradiction for $L(h):=c\cdot h$

Comment: Let f(x)=|x|, and $L(h)$ be an arbitrary linear function ,i.e. $L(h)=m\cdot h + b$. We want to show the Speedproperty does not hld for $x_0=0$. Then $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|h|}{h}-m+\frac{b}{h}$. To Show $\exists_{\epsilon>0}\forall_{\delta>0}|h|<\delta\wedge |\frac{|h|}{h}-m+\frac{b}{h}|\geq\epsilon$ As $h\rightarrow 0\Rightarrow $ we get $|\pm 1 - m + 0|$, i.e it is not $0$ if we let $h$ converge from both sides.

Comment: I have some further Questions on this idea that a function 'dominates' over another. Please have a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105199/what-does-it-mean-if-a-function-f-converges-faster-to-a-value-than-an-other-fu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the already given answer

We have said that a function $x_0$ is differentiable if and only if the values around $x_0$ can be described arbitrarily precise in a specific neighbourhood around $x_0$ with a linear growth rate.

To formalize what I mean:

$f:I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is differentiable if and only if there exists a linear function $L:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)}{h}=0$$

> In the book where I have read this there is remark where more
>   information is given about this property and what it means:
>
> *In this formulation the differentuability states that the increase $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ of the function can be approximated so well by the
>   value $L(h)$ of a linear map $L$ that the difference
>   $R(h):=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)$ goes with $h\rightarrow 0$ faster to $0$
>   than $h$ itself.*

Now we also have the definition that $f(x)$ goes to Zero faster than g(x) as $x\rightarrow0$ means $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$

To get more some more intuition About the statement: By the definition of limits we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\iff\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}:|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\epsilon$$

Conveying this result on the Situation here we have

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{R(h)}{h}=0\iff\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}:|h|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{R(h)}{h}|<\epsilon$$

Now imagine if you choose $\epsilon=0.5$ I get $\delta=5$

You are only interested in the local approximation

Since we have $|h|<5\Rightarrow |\frac{R(h)}{h}|<0.5$

We also have $|h|<1<5\Rightarrow |\frac{R(h)}{h}|<0.5$

which means The error of the approximation around $x_0$, i.e $(x_0-1,x_0+1)$ is smaller than $0.5$ because we have $|R|<0.5\cdot |h|$

Another example suppose I choose $\epsilon = 0.5$ again for another function and this time I get $\delta = 0.1$

Then again I know that the error of approximation by the linear function in $(x_0-0.1,x_0+0.1)$ is (much) smaller than $\epsilon$ because

$|R|<0.5\cdot |h|$

Comment: This 'faster' therefore means in a sense that if you have a small distance around $x_0$ call the distance $\epsilon$ then the Approximation is smaller or equal to this distance.

Comment: Scratch equal in smaller or equal it is strictly smaller