# What does it mean if a function $f$ converges faster to a value than an other function?

Tags: complex-analysis

This Question is related to a previous one of mine

My Questions are marked in bold

[What is the connection between a derivative and the linear approximation? (First order Taylor)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096376/what-is-the-connection-between-a-derivative-and-the-linear-approximation-first)

The answer says that the Definition of

$$f(x) \text{ goes to Zero faster than } g(x) \text{ as } x\rightarrow 0 \text{ "means" } \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 (*)$$

One generalitzation of above would be

$$f(x) \text{ goes to Zero faster than } g(x) \text{ as } x\rightarrow x_0 \text{ "means" } \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 (**)$$

**Now my first Question is what would it mean if a function $f(x)$ goes to $c$ faster than $g(x)$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$? Where $c$ is a complex number.**

For $(*)$ we have the prerequisite that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)= 0$

Or more generally for $(**)$ one has $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)= 0$

**My next Question is what is the connection with the infinite case?**

I.e. If we have

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)= \infty$ and also

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$$

**In this context what does it mean if a function $f$ dominates over another function $g$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

It would mean
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-c}{g(x)-c}=0$$

For the second question:

In my understanding, ‘$f$ dominates $g$’ can often mean $f$ diverges faster than $g$, and thus is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f}{g}=\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac gf=0$$